# unable to find plugin: eosio::wallet_api_plugin

Tags: nodeos

I have just configure EOS reading [this](https://medium.com/@blockgenic/eosio-single-node-testnet-setup-mac-os-7cb5dce2205b) article. Now when I run the command

```
./nodeos -e -p eosio --plugin eosio::wallet_api_plugin --plugin eosio::chain_api_plugin --plugin eosio::account_history_api_plugin
```

this gives me the following error:

```
2018-09-08T09:07:26.172 thread-0   main.cpp:131                  main                 ] /Users/abdulmanan7/eos/libraries/appbase/application.cpp(309): Throw in function appbase::abstract_plugin &appbase::application::get_plugin(const string &) const
Dynamic exception type: boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<std::runtime_error> >
std::exception::what: unable to find plugin: eosio::wallet_api_plugin
```

I don't know what is the issue; can anyone help me out please?

When I remove wallect_api_plugin I get this error:

```
unable to find plugin: eosio::account_history_api_plugin
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [release notes of v1.2.0](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/releases/tag/v1.2.0), the `wallet_api_plugin` has been removed from `nodeos`:

> - it is no longer possible to run the `wallet_plugin` or `wallet_api_plugin`
>     as part of `nodeos`. This configuration has not been recommended for
>     many versions as it places private information in the same process
>     space as unrelated RPCs and the execution environment for untrusted
>     code (WebAssembly). This release officially removes the support.

Comment: i update question please have a look again